# Remote Desktop for Windows XP Professional?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, remote-desktop

I have looked through ServerFault's archives but can't find the answer I am looking for.

I am currently working on a network of around 15 computers, they are connected to a unix server for a specific piece of software for their client management system.

I am looking for a way to remote control the computers from one 'admin' computer - only within the LAN though, nothing needs to be setup for outside remote control.

Everything I have seen seems to be based on dialling into the office and controlling the computers that way.

Is there anything optimised for local use only? I have tried remote desktop connection, but when I click browser and select the workgroup name I get a message about there being no terminals found.

Is there anything anyone can recommend?

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each XP machine, right click on my computer > properties, choose the remote tab and make sure 'Allow users to connect remotely to this computer' is checked. Admins will be allowed in by default but you can add other users here.

Forget about browsers.  Open remote desktop connection, type in the machine name and you should connect to it.

Comment: Ahh, so once the remote connection is allowed then they will become "Terminals" as far as remote desktop connection is concerned?

Comment: You will still have to type the name in your RDP client, as XP RDP does not advertise itself like a Server RDP does...

Answer (score 2):

There's remote control and there's remote connections.

If you use the remote access with Windows, you log in with your own session. That's the remote tab on the computer properties, allowing remote desktop connections with Remote Desktop Protocol. Ubuntu can then connect using terminal services.

If you want remote control (i.e., supporting users) for free, use VNC. It has some quirks, but UltraVNC works for us, and it's Win7 compatible. Be aware that without special clients, the connection isn't encrypted, so passwords can be sniffed unless you direct it through SSH tunnels or such.

There are clients for RDP and VNC available for Linux if that's what you're using for administration.

Comment: +1 for UltraVNC for Win2Win connections.  I usually use RealVNC Client to go from Linux/Unix/Mac-to-Win (running UltraVNC server).

Answer (score 1):

Remote desktop will work well for a LAN, [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) is another option that I have used in the past.

Comment: I like Tight, but Ultra provides encryption built-in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Remote Desktops tool but you'll need to add the workstations manually. Since the workstations aren't technically running Terminal Services, they won't be "found" by any TS tools.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309375